# How to views-filter attached field value by calculated values?

Tags: 7, views

I just want to create a simple "IN" filter for my taxonomy field with values that I calculate in the views_handler_filter subclass.

My subclass of views_handler_filter implements the function views_handler_filter->query(). I need to require that the tid of a taxonomy_term_reference field is in an array that I build there. How can I build the query to filter by field value?

```
views_plugin_query_default::add_where($group, $field, $value = NULL, $operator = NULL)
```

When calling $query->add_where(), the $field argument is simply described as "The name of the field to check." How can I join the filter query to the field data table and build my $field argument correctly for the taxonomy_term_reference field I need to filter by?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my current problem in a similar way to the solution here: http://drupal.org/node/1259914

1. Added a filter to the view with my taxonomy field as "not empty"
2. Implemented hook_views_query_alter() to call $query->add_where with my field_table_name.field_data_column and the values I wanted to accept with the 'IN' operator.

That said, I'm still interested in the views_handler_filter->query() solution(s).